# outlook mailitem in explorer mode is old

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, explorer

I have an intermittent updating problem with an outlook mailitem in the explorer mode on a public folder of an exchange server. The subject (or perhaps any other part as well) of a mailitem does not seem to update itself at times.

Specifically, the subject of the mailitem shown in the explorer mode is dissimilar to that shown in the inspector mode. In other words, the explorer mode is old, therefore needs updating or synchronization.

Hitting F9 (send/receive) to update the public folder does not seem to help.

I would like to know if this anomaly can be detected (and perhaps perform manual updates/synchronization) using an outlook macro.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Have you checked this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278150/get-previous-mailitem-when-reply-on-outlook

Answer (score 1):

Some properties, factors unknown, update on saving only.

The subject of the mail in the explorer view should change when you manually close the item, if you agree to save changes. Should be the same if you manually saved regularly.

If you want more than a simple save:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MarkInUseSaveCurrentItem()

Dim currItem As Object
Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

If InStr(LCase(currItem.subject), LCase("Barok is working on this")) = 0 Then
    currItem.subject = "Barok is working on this. To avoid conflicts do not open. " & currItem.subject
End If

currItem.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the test code. However, manually or automatically saving the mailitem in the inspector mode does not reflect the modifications in the outlook explorer. However, after an arbitrary lapse of time, the explorer finally seems to show the latest updates. Is there a caching problem causing the delay in display? Strange.

Comment: Got nothing more. Apparently your setup is different than mine.